# UWP DatePicker custom strings for month

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, datepicker, win-universal-app

I am doing UWP application for non English users. I need to use DatePicker but I don't like that the months' names are written in English, I also dont want to show month with their numeral values. How can I set my own list of string to show it on the months picker?

Comment: What language/string do you want to use?

Comment: @JaydenGu I want to use Georgian Language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the region from english to spanish or someone else region then the months names is to be changed to spanish language or someone else language. This mean the name for months and day like Fri, Mon, etc, Is get the name from region. And is not fixed with the english name.

**UPDATE:**

Try to put this somewhere when is after or before InitializeComponent();

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ka-GE"); // Georgia culture code. I'm not sure this is correct.
```

Comment: That doesnt work for me, I want to use Georgian language. can I use my own strings to replace original?

Answer (score 3):

As I known, the `DatePicker` does not provide the mechanism of custom own strings for month.

If you want to use Georgian in your app, you don't need to custom string for month. The `DatePicker` support [Globalization and localization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/globalizing/globalizing-portal).

You can specify the supported languages in the app's manifest. To modify app's manifest, we can select the "**Package.appxmanifest**" in "**Solution Explorer**" and right click, then select "**View Code**".

For example:

```
<Resources>
  <Resource Language="ka-ge" />
  <Resource Language="en-us" />
</Resources>
```

When the user sets in **Settings** > **Time & language** > **Region & language**, add **Georgian language** and **Set as default**.

[image]

The month in `DatePicker` will show in Georgian.