# How can i change language for CalendarDatePicker UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, localization, calendar

How can i change language for this calendar into Japanese not using CalendarIndentifier.

MainPage's XAML

```
<Button content="Click" Click="Button_Click" />
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "ja-jp";    
    testDialog dialog = new testDialog();      
    await dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

My calendar is in testDialog.

testDialog's xaml

```
<CalendarDatePicker />
```

CalendarDatePicker's language will not change immediately, it will change after i close the app and open

My current OS's language is: en-us

Comment: I'm not familiar with that control, but from this similar question (though no accepted answer) it looks like there should be a `Language` property.  That said, I can't find mention in the documentation.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40677814/uwp-change-calendardatepicker-language-in-runtime

Comment: ps. This thread implies that the information's inheritted from the related thread's current culture: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35874987/361842

Comment: Yeah i've read these link but none of them are working...

Comment: Do you have Japanese language pack installed on the computer?

Comment: Could you add some more info on the current context; i.e. what's your OS language, what language is the current thread, is the language included in the app's manifest, is the thread's language set before the CalenderDatePicker`'s `InitializeComponent` is called?  Also any supporting code related to changing the threads language / showing where that sits in relation to initialising the component may be helpful.

Comment: edited, please take a look, i've just found out something

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.globalization.applicationlanguages.primarylanguageoverride):

> When you set the PrimaryLanguageOverride, this is immediately reflected in the ApplicationLanguages.Languages property. **However, this change may not take effect immediately on resources loaded in the app UI.**
>
> To make sure the app responds to such changes, you can listen to the QualifierValues property on a default resource context and take whatever actions may be needed to reload resources. Those requirements may vary depending on the UI framework used by the app, and it may be necessary to restart the app.

Comment: any idea how can i reload the CalendarDatePicker after PrimaryLanguageOverriding ? everything works fine except the CalendarDatePicker

Comment: Tried a few times, but without success. I think this is the one case that is "necessary to restart the app".

Comment: Problem when restarting the app is my default app language is English if i  PrimaryLanguageOverriding="en" at the beginning calendar's language won't change to Japanese too

Comment: Have you tried @JohnLBevan's suggestion to set `CalendarView.Language` property? With my test, it did work.

Comment: Mine is CalendarDatePicker, i tried to use CalendarDatePicker.Language="ja-JP" but i see no affection

Comment: @GoodVibethisday With my testing, you need to set `PrimaryLanguageOverriding` and `CalendarDatePicker.Language`. Then you also need to restart the app.

Comment: Thanks you but "you also need to restart the app" isn't the point i'm heading to

Comment: I am having same problems as @GoodVibethisday, where the greyed out values for 'day month year' (ie BEFORE hitting dropdown) are in the original locale. Yes, upon restarting the app as suggested it corrects itself, but like GoodVibe, I want to update it dynamically. How?